# Disadvantages of using ZFS recordsize 16k instead of 128k

Tags: zfs, qemu, performance-tuning

I'm using Proxmox on a dedicated server. For production I'm still using ext4, but I decided to start messing around with ZFS.

So I have created two separate ZFS storage pools with diffrent recordsizes:

- 128k for everything except MySQL/InnoDB
- 16k for MySQL/InnoDB (because 16k is default InnoDB page size which I'm using)

I have added that 16k pool to check if it really makes difference for MySQL/InnoDB database performance. So it really does. I have about 40% more transactions per second and 25% lower latency (I have tested this thoroughly with [sysbench](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/sysbench) and [tpcc](https://github.com/Percona-Lab/sysbench-tpcc)).

**For practical reasons at this moment I would prefer to use one big pool with 16k recordsize instead of two separate parts (16k and 128k).** I know, that I can create subvolumes on single ZFS pool and give them diffrent recordsizes, but this is also something I want to avoid. I prefer to keep this manageable from Proxmox GUI.

---

My questions:

1. What disadvantages can I encounter if I start using a small (16k) recordsize for everything instead of 128k (it was default on Proxmox)?
2. Does the QEMU disk image have an equivalent of innodb_page_size? If it does - what size is it?

   I have tried to check it with `qemu-img info`:

   ```
    $ qemu-img info vm-100-disk-0.raw
    image: vm-100-disk-0.raw
    file format: raw
    virtual size: 4 GiB (4294967296 bytes)
    disk size: 672 MiB
   ```

---

Server usage is:

- containers for www/php (tons of small files, but inside a container disk file)
- containers for java/spring applications (they produce a lot of logs)
- containers for mysql/innodb databases (no explanation required)
- local backup/restore operations including compressing backups
- messing around with large gzip files (not every day, low priority)

Comment: Use the appropriate record size for each application. I'm not sure what else would be acceptable.

Comment: I don't know what is appropriate for each application. Default 128k seems to be appropriate for very large files, but it is default in ZFS (or just in proxmox?). I don't understand why.

Comment: 128K is fine...

Comment: @ewwhite I know it is fine. But I want to get rid of 128k part and keep only 16k part, for simple single storage which is also very good for MySQL/InnoDB. I have precised my question now, because that was unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** It really depends on your expected use case. As a general rule, the default 128K recordsize is a good choice on mechanical disks (where access latency is dominated by seek time + rotational delay). For an all-SSD pool, I would probably use 16K or at most 32K (only if the latter provides a significant compression efficiency increase for your data).

**Long answer:** With an HDD pool, I recommend sticking with the default 128K recordsize for datasets and using 128K volblocksize for zvol also. The rationale is that access latency for a 7.2K RPM HDD is dominated by seek time, which does *not* scale with recordsize/volblocksize. Lets do some math: a 7.2K HDD has an average seek time of 8.3ms, while reading a 128K block only takes ~1ms. So commanding an head seek (with 8ms+ delay) to read a small 16K blocks seems wasteful, especially considering that for smaller reads/writes you are still impaired by r/m/w latency. Moreover, a small recordsize means a bigger metadata overhead and worse compression. So while InnoDB issues 16K IOs, and for a dedicated dataset one can use 16K recordsize to avoid r/m/w and write amplification, for a mixed-use datasets (ie: ones you use not only for the DB itself but for more general workloads also) I would suggest staying at 128K, especially considering the compression impact from small recordsize.

However, for an SSD pool I would use a much smaller volblocksize/recordsize, possibly in the range of 16-32K. The rationale is that SSD have much lower access time but limited endurance, so writing a full 128K block for smaller writes seems excessive. Moreover, the IO bandwidth amplification commanded by large recordsize is much more concerning on an high-IOPs device as modern SSDs (ie: you risk to saturate your bandwidth *before* reaching IOPs limit).

Comment: What about the impact on compression with lower record sizes? I'm not usually concerned about SSD endurance in most situations.

Comment: @ewwhite Well, it depends on what it is stored on disk. Taking as example a small linux vm with 20G nominal size: recordsize=128k yields 7.2G, recordsize=32k shows 7.8G and recordsize=16k shows 8.6G - so you lose ~10% at each step. But, as stated above, this is completely dependent on what you are storing.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend tuning ***if and when*** you encounter a problem.

ZFS defaults to 128K record sizes, and that is acceptable and valid for most configurations and applications.

Exceptions to this include:

- certain database applications; a smaller value may be appropriate. 
  The tradeoff is compression will be way less effective, which may have a greater impact on performance than the higher transaction count!!
- large media workloads (e.g. video editing); a larger value is useful
- specific workloads that fall outside the normal ZFS use cases

If you feel that the performance of the database benchmark is better with a certain record size, use it!

But have you tested with a realistic *non-benchmarking* workload to make sure you're adjusting for the right thing?

Comment: Well, I usually do tuning "if and when there is a problem". However that huge performance difference between 128k and 16k for InnoDB showed me how huge difference can be with ZFS. Thank you for list of exceptions. So... I should keep and maintain two storages, right?

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, it's a recommendation to set "recordsize=16K "according to zfs'documentation itself.

https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Performance%20and%20Tuning/Workload%20Tuning.html#innodb

EDIT:
I just reverted this setting after changing it for less than 12 hours on a proxmox server for a virtual server with quite a big database (>60GB of data).
The server seriously dropped behind in analyzing data.
In fact the 'z_rd_int_*'  processes jumped from a low CPU usage to about 5% each while the 'z_wr_int_*' processed dropped in cpu usage - probably because less data was treated.

However, changing the hash algorithm to edonr (`zfs set checksum=edonr vmpool`) did have a positive impact: `perf top` no longer shows `SHA256TransformBlocks` as the top kernal function.

So the recommendation does not appear to be good in all cases - it can be reverted to the original set.